# IBM Websphere App server - After Migration, the profile won't start because ADML3000E: Cannot locate systemlaunch.properties at path

Tags: websphere

I have migrated a WAS profile from a server to another but when I wwant to start the profile it won't because of this error:

```
[2/23/24 9:42:04:236 UTC] 00000001 DefaultLaunch W   ADML3000E: The tool is unable to locate the systemlaunch.properties file: java.io.IOException: Cannot locate systemlaunch.properties at path: E:\WebSphere\AppServer\properties\systemlaunch\base\8.0_64.systemlaunch.properties
```

I am unable to find where this path is defined, because on the new machine, the path of systemlaunch.properties is different and I need to adjust it but can't find it.

Comment: I believe the base location of the systemlaunch properties is pulled from the variable definition of WAS_INSTALL_ROOT. To check that, go to your profile, in the /config directory, then drill down to your cell, server, and node directories for a variables.xml file, and see if that property is present and incorrect in any of them. It theoretically should be defined at the node level, but given that it's not correct, I'd check the other scopes just in case.